# How to add Vietnamese fonts into jspdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, jspdf

I am using JSPDF to export pdf. But I don't know how to add Vietnamese fonts into jspdf in order to export pdf with Vietnamese. Can you show me how to do it ? Thank you very much.

Comment: You should provide us some code of the error you're receiving to clarify the question

Answer (score 1):

You should check their documentation, they've recently added UTF8 support, at this page you'll find the method **addFont**: https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#addFont

To add a custom font file to pdfjs you could check out this: https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-vFS.html#~addFileToVFS

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/bocko/pen/RyGBKg

```
    const pdf = new jsPDF({
      unit: 'pt',
      orientation: 'p',
      format: [pdfSize, pdfSize],
      //lineHeight: 1.2
    });

  // define custom font
  pdf.addFileToVFS("ConsolasHex.ttf", [base64 encoding of font])
  // add custom font to file
  pdf.addFont("ConsolasHex.ttf", "ConsolasHex", "Bold");
  pdf.setFont("ConsolasHex","Bold");
  pdf.setFontSize(12);
```